# How do filter two (only visually) joined expressions in AngularJS 1.5.11

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

**Scenario:**
I have a array of items, that each item has properties (model,id),

```
$scope.arrayOfItems = [{
                         model : 'L_',
                         id : 01
                       },
                       {
                         model : 'L_',
                         id : 2323
                       },
                       {
                         model : 'L_',
                         id : 434
                       }
                    ];
```

For each item, both of these properties are merged to form a item **Label**.
I'm trying filter the two **VISUALLY** merged expressions

```
{{::item.model}}{{::item.id}}

model = 'L_';
id    = 03;
```

So the result would be **L_03**

If I wish to search for the item Label **'L_2323'**  in the input field and type **'L_'** followed by the id, all the list items disappear.

I want to be able to type **'L_2323'** and have the corresponding list item being displayed

I understand that I can loop through and merge all the models and id's and put inside a array in the controller and display each item of that array inside the main item's loop, but that seems like a wasteful solution and I'm trying to solve the problem in a more pragmatic way

I have added a codepen of this bug
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Jammi/pen/gjerJN)

Comment: Write a custom filter that searches for a match from a `item.model+item.id` string

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Thanks, I understand most filtering techniques but can you give me a simple example of what you  mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write a custom filter that scans the array for a match of `model + id` together. Here is a quick demo of what it can look like:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(arrayOfItems, input) {
    var res = [];
    if (input) {
      for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfItems.length; i++) {
        var item = arrayOfItems[i];
        if ((item.model + item.id).match(input)) { // match
          res.push(item);
        }
      }
      // don't return an empty array if nothing was found
      return (res.length > 0) ? res : arrayOfItems; 
    }
    return arrayOfItems; // default (no input given)
  };
});

app.controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.arrayOfItems = [{
      model: 'L_',
      id: 01
    },
    {
      model: 'L_',
      id: 2323
    },
    {
      model: 'L_',
      id: 434
    }
  ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

    <span>Filter your search : 
      <input type="text" ng-model="searchFilter">
      {{searchFilter}}
    </span>
    
    <hr>

    <div ng-repeat="item in arrayOfItems | myFilter: searchFilter">
      {{item.model}}{{item.id}}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic search code can be something like this:

```js
const arr = [{
  model: 'L_',
  id: '01'
}, {
  model: 'L_',
  id: '2323'
}, {
  model: 'L_',
  id: '434'
}];

const search = function(searchTerm) {
  return arr.filter(item => {
    const fullName = item.model + item.id;
    return fullName.includes(searchTerm);
  })
}

const searResult1 = search('01');
console.log(searResult1);

const searResult2 = search('L_');
console.log(searResult2);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/90Lc7dt8/8/

What we are doing here is:

1. Create a variable `fullName` that contains the information you want to search
2. Use filter to return items that match the pattern

Now all you need is the angular code for the input.

1. Use `ng-model` on input
2. Put the search function as a watch function
3. Use `ng-repeat` to list out the results

Here is an angular example on codepen:
https://codepen.io/bergur/pen/yqKaKw?editors=1010#0